# what is Valid email Pattern angular 4 or 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, formbuilder

I am using `formbuilder` and i have used below pattern

```
this.registerForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      title : ['',Validators.required],
      fname : ['',Validators.required],
      lname : ['',Validators.required],
      tel : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[+][0-9]+$')]],
      email : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$')]],
      cname : ['', Validators.required],
      role : ['']
    });
```

It's validating email address but it is not validating `.com or .xxxx` in the email. For example it is considering below email id as valid email:

```
ambuj.webmasters@xxxx
```

It should consider it as invalid. Valid email id could be:

```
ambuj.webmasters@xxxxx.com
```

Comment: Why are not using `Validators.email`, if I can ask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have tried `Validators.email` as well but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern,

```
this.registerForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      title : ['',Validators.required],
      fname : ['',Validators.required],
      lname : ['',Validators.required],
      tel : ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[+][0-9]+$')]],
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)])],
      cname : ['', Validators.required],
      role : ['']
    });
```

Comment: meanwhile I have used `required pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$"` in HTML and it is also working fine for me.